# The syntax of the command is incorrect for 'type dist/project/{runtime, script, main}.js | 7z > elements.js.gz'

Tags: linux, command-line, cmd.exe, ms-dos

Trying to learn to use mac commands conversion to windows.

I am trying to run command in cmd

```
'type dist/project/{runtime, script, main}.js | 7z > elements.js.gz'
```

and getting not much elaborated error

> The syntax of the command is incorrect

I have installed `7z` set path to `C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: The `{a,b,c}` expansions (note no spaces) do not exist in the Cmd shell used by Windows. It understands only a few features common to Unix shells, namely `|` and `<` `>` redirection, but that's about it – you won't be able to use most Bourne/Bash/Zsh language features in Cmd at all.

Your options:

- Type in the three names in full.

  ```
  type dist\a.js dist\b.js dist\c.js
  ```
- Install a Windows port of Bash (widely available, e.g. msys bundled with Git; Cygwin is another option).
- Learn PowerShell – while *completely* different from Bash/Bourne shell, it is nevertheless far more powerful than Cmd.

---

Second problem: `type` is actually a built-in command in Cmd, and will most likely misunderstand / as the path separator. While Windows itself accepts it, many programs insist that you use `\` as normal. This is especially common for Cmd built-ins.

The reason is that / is the standard option prefix, e.g. `dir /w`.

---

Third problem: `7z` is not the same as `gzip`. It can *handle* gzip-compressed files, but is still a different program and – if I remember – it doesn't support the same "pipe" mode of operation. You can only tell it to archive existing files into a new file, not stdin to stdout.